# How to calculate in email developing using handlebarJs

Tags: email, handlebars.js, sendgrid

As you can see in:

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

I want to calculate this formula and it should give me the value(140) back But it didn't work. I guess it because handlebarjs grammatical errors in sendgrid. So how to write it correctly. Thank you for helping me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

Handlebars is a templating language with support for [simple expressions](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/expressions.html#basic-usage). Expressions include rendering content, iterating over content and conditionals. There are also some built in helpers within Handlebars, like [data formatting](https://docs.sendgrid.com/for-developers/sending-email/using-handlebars#formatdate).

However, Handlebars does not evaluate arbitrary JavaScript code within the templates. When you write `{{ productNum1 + productNum2 + 100 }}` that is a JavaScript expression that within the context of a JavaScript interpreter you would expect to evaluate to a number. Handlebars is not a JavaScript interpreter though, so it will not evaluate and that is why your template does not calculate the formula.

Since you run code to send emails via SendGrid with this template syntax, you should evaluate any code like this and send it as data to be rendered.

Comment: No problem! If it helped, please do mark the question as correct so that others can see that it helped too. Thanks!